# Induction proof of an Haskell custom function

Tags: haskell, induction

I'm studying induction and I've some problems to figure out how to complete an induction proof of my "destutter" function that deletes consecutive duplicates in a list:

```
destutter [] = []                                          Destrutter.1
destutter (x:xs) = x : (destutter (dropWhile (== x) xs))   Destrutter.2
```

And this is the assumption:

```
destutter (destutter xs) == destutter xs
```

This is what I've done so far:

Proving the base case (empty list)

```
-- BASE CASE --

Left side:
destutter (destutter xs)
== {- xs = [] -}
destutter (destutter [])
== {- Destrutter.1, destutter [] = [] -}
destutter ([])
== {- Destrutter.1, destutter [] = [] -}
[]

Right side:
destrutter xs
== {- xs = [] -}
destrutter []
== {- Destrutter.1, destutter [] = [] -}
[]

Left side == Right side -> Proved
```

Proving the general case:

```
-- GENERAL CASE --

Assumption: destutter (destutter xs) == destutter xs
Claim: destutter (destutter (x:xs)) == destutter (x:xs)

destutter (destutter (x:xs))
== {- Destrutter.2, destutter (x:xs) = x : (destutter (dropWhile (== x) xs)) -}
destutter (x: (destutter (dropWhile (== x) xs)))
== {- Destrutter.2, destutter (x:xs) = x : (destutter (dropWhile (== x) xs)) -}
x : (destrutter (dropWhile (==x) (destutter (dropWhile (== x) xs))))
```

Here is where I've some problems: I can't figure out how to use the assumption to get to:

```
destrutter (x:xs)
```

I've tried different ways but no one seems to be the correct one. 
Are the steps I did good? Is my reasoning way correct?

Comment: As a side note: `destutter = map head . group`.

Comment: maybe you should try to *proof* that `head . destutter . (dropWhile (== x)) /= x` first

Comment: You need to get rid of the outer `dropWhile` - note, it will never change the list, to prove that you need to show that the first element of the list `destutter (dropWhile (== x) xs))` is never equal to `x`, therefore the `dropWhile (==x)` will return immediately. Once you have done that, you can use the inductive hypothesis on `destrutter (destutter (dropWhile (== x) xs))` to get `destutter (dropWhile (== x) xs)`. Strictly speaking, to do this, you need to prove that the list `dropWhile (==x) xs` is smaller than the list `x:xs` - this is "obvious" but probably needs to be proved anyways.

Comment: @user2407038 
First of all, thank you for the support.
How can I prove that `destutter (dropWhile (== x) xs))` is never equal to x (that is true, off course)? 
This is my main problem...